# Select all records except the last pair fpr each userid

Tags: ms-access

I have table in Access which has two columns (USERID, TITLE). Every user can have more than one title. I want to select all USERID and titles except the last pair of USERID and TITLE for each user.
BTW, before this I could select the last pair of USERID and TITLE for each user.but i dont know how can i delete these record from the first table 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If the table also has a primary key field id (as it should), then the following should work in the SQL view of a query:

```
SELECT `userid`, `title` FROM `table` WHERE id <> 
(SELECT MAX(`id`) FROM `table` WHERE `userid` = [the user id in question]);
```

This assumes, of course, that by last you mean the record with the largest id.